# How do I know which the average search by value complexity of a data structure?

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, complexity-theory

Which of the following containers have average search by value complexity equal to O(log(n))?

Which ones have O(n) and O(n^2)?

```
std::vector 
std::list 
std::deque 
std::set 
std::multiset 
std::unordered_set 
std::unordered_multiset sorted 
std::vector sorted 
std::list sorted 
std::deque sorted
```

Comment: Why did you tag this C?

Comment: O(N^2) for search is pretty special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard specifies the complexity of the relevant functions. Get a copy, or read a good reference. (See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find.)

They're all pretty much what you'd expect.